# Find a certain invariant angle, given a constraint on perimeter

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Each side of square ABCD has length 1 unit. Points P and Q are on AB, and DA, respectively. Find angle PCQ if the perimeter of triangle APQ is 2.

I used trigonometry to solve this problem, and my answer is 45 degrees. I would like to know if there are any other, more elegant methods to solve this problem.

Comment: Using trigonometry is the most ‘elegant’ way, as far as I can see.

Comment: Is there a reason for the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]This was done quickly, it may be incorrect.

Notice that since the perimeter of $APQ$ is $2$ (i.e., half of that of the square), we have $AB+AD = AQ+AP+PQ$ and $AB+AD = AQ+QD +AP+PB$. Combining these two equations obtain, $PQ = QD+PB$.  Thus, there is a point $X$ on $PQ$ such that $PX = PB$ and $QX = QD$. With this in mind, extend $PB$ to a point $W$ in the same direction but with $PW = PQ$. Similarly  extend $QD$ to a point $V$ such that $QV = PQ$. Now let angle $QCD = \theta$ and angle $PCB = \alpha$. Notice that triangle $PQC$ is congruent to triangles $QCV$ and $PCW$ and also that triangle $DCV$ is congruent to triangle  $PBC$. Hence it follows that the angle $PCQ$ is $\theta +\alpha$, and that $2\theta+2\alpha = 90^\circ$ which gives the required $45$ degree angle.

Comment: Nice idea! (+1) Your construction would be however more understandable if you start with $BW=DQ, DV=BP$ and claim $BP+DQ=PQ$.

Comment: will edit an add that soon